# I thought we had already passed this error and qubit threshold?

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, experimental-realization

As outlined in [Quantum Computing Progress and Prospects](https://www.nap.edu/catalog/25196/quantum-computing-progress-and-prospects) published this year, on page 169-171 there is the diagram showing that we are at the 10's of qubits mark. Looking into the diagram further there is the statement prior that states ,

> The first benchmark machine is the class of digital (gate-based)
>   quantum computers containing around $2^{4}$ qubits with average gate
>   error rate better than 5 percent, which first became available in
>   2017.

However, when I look at [Quantum Computing Report](https://quantumcomputingreport.com/scorecards/qubit-count/) I find that there are a couple of companies past the 50+ qubit count to get to the next point. Is the report already outdated, or am I missing something?